# Team City with Visual Studio solution build steps

Tags: visual-studio-2012, teamcity

I have a Visual Studio 2012 solution containing a Windows service project and a web application project.

I want Team City (version 8.0.3) to create two zip files (one for the service and one for the web app) that I will deploy manually.

Should I create a build step to build the entire solution, followed by a build step to publish the Windows service and a build step to publish the web site (via publish profiles). Then use Artifact paths in General Settings to zip up these two published folders?

Or should I have just one build step to build the solution and then use the Artifact paths to create the two zip files?

Or is there a better way than either of the above?

Answer (score 0):

You have to ask yourself if these two projects are linked and in which manner they should be built together.

My feeling is : if your projects are in the same solution, they are linked in some ways and have to be built together.

Then, you should build your solution (`sln`) and not projects (`*proj`).

**Application organization**

Generally, your build server should not redefine -too much- the way your applications are organized. You should always use your plateform application descriptor to build your applications.

In case of .NET and Visual Studio, [the application descriptor is your solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b142f8e7.aspx) (`sln`). It defines the needs and how your application have to be built.

If your project have to be built separately, they should be in differents solution unless you prefer to create specific solution configuration (in addition to Release & Debug).
Anyway, the solution is still the build entry point.

**TeamCity**

Speaking about TeamCity, different and standalone applications should be in separate ***build configurations***.

The pure build (code compilation) should be in one ***build step*** and you should not use too much code compilation runners in one build configuration.

Your build configurations should reflect your applications farm logic.

If you need to link them in some ways which are related to packaging for example, you can link your ***build configurations*** through [***snapshot or artifact dependency***](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+Dependencies).